# Gulp Watch, SASS não le alteração

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulpjs, npm

Meu GULP:

```js
var gulp      = require('gulp'),
 sass        = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
 imagemin    = require('gulp-imagemin'),
 changed     = require('gulp-changed'),
 browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./assets/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({compass: false}))
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('jpg', function() {
 gulp.src('./assets/img/**/*.jpg')
  .pipe(changed('./dist/img/'))
  .pipe(imagemin({
   progressive: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img/'));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(['./dist/css/**', './views/**'], {
        server: {
            baseDir: './',
            index: './views/index.html'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function () { 
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('./assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Quando executo, tudo funciona, mas o SASS não detecta alterações.
O Index.html funciona.

O que pode estar errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no módulo **gulp-ruby-sass** que é na minha humilde opinião ultrapassada. Te aconselho a fazer o seguinte (prometo que não vai doer):

- Rode o comando `npm uninstall --save | --save-dev gulp-ruby-sass`, o *pipe* foi apenas para dividir os parâmetros, você deverá escolher apenas um, isso dependerá aonde foi que você instalou a dependência, se foi dentro de `dependencies: {}` então é `--save` ou se foi dentro de `devDependencies: {}` então é `--save-dev`. Para mais informações acesse https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall
- Logo em seguida instale o módulo `npm install --save-dev gulp-sass`, esse módulo é uma versão mais atualizada do **gulp-ruby-sass** com algumas melhorias (inclusive de performance).
- Por último, vá até o `gulpfile.js` e substitua o parâmetro de `require()` de *gulp-ruby-sass* para *gulp-sass* e rode a task novamente.

---

## Update

Também te aconselho a utilizar a extensão `**/*.(js|css|jpg|etc)` pois utilizando o marcador `**` você consegue rodar as *tasks* de uma forma recursiva, ou seja, a *task* será rodada dentro dos sub-diretórios do diretório especificado.

Como por exemplo a task `gulp sass` definida `gulp.task('./assets/sass/*.scss')` rodará apenas para os arquivos `.scss` dentro de `./assets/sass/`, porém se você programar a *task* para rodar recursivamente, ela terá acesso a sub-diretórios dentro de `./assets/sass/`, ficando dessa forma `gulp.task('./assets/sass/**/*.scss')`, simples né?

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil pra você, ficaria feliz se pudesse marcar ela como a correta.

Comment: Marcado :) e foi o que fiz, rodou perfeitamente.